# How to list files in S3 within given start & end date range using AWS C++ SDK

Tags: c++, file, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, date-range

I could not find any method or sample code to list files from S3 created within a given date range.
I tried `WithIfModifiedSince`, `SetIfModifiedSince` with `GetObjectRequest`.

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/ListObjectsRequest.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/Object.h>

/* list_files_s3_create_withen_given_date_range */

{
    Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client;

    Aws::S3::Model::ListObjectsRequest objects_request;
    objects_request.WithBucket(bucket_name);

    /* This lists all the files in s3 bucket. */
    /* But how to get files within a given date range. */

    //Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest object_request;
    //object_request.SetBucket(bucket_name);
    //object_request.WithIfModifiedSince(DateTime)

    auto list_objects_outcome = s3_client.ListObjects(objects_request);

    if (list_objects_outcome.IsSuccess())
    {
        Aws::Vector<Aws::S3::Model::Object> object_list =
            list_objects_outcome.GetResult().GetContents();

        for (auto const &s3_object : object_list)
        {
            std::cout << "* " << s3_object.GetKey() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

//------------------------------------

```
Aws::Utils::DateTime startdt = Aws::Utils::DateTime::DateTime("2019-10-23T10:00:00Z", Aws::Utils::DateFormat::ISO_8601); 

Aws::Utils::DateTime enddt = Aws::Utils::DateTime::Now(); Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest object_request; object_request.SetBucket(bucket_name); object_request.WithIfModifiedSince(startdt); 
//object_request.SetIfModifiedSince(startdt); 

auto object_outcome = s3_client.GetObject(objects_request);
if (object_outcome.IsSuccess())
{
   std::cout << object_outcome.GetResultWithOwnership().GetETag() << std::endl;
}


The code is not returning any object(file) from s3 bucket why ?
```

Comment: "but it's not working" is not a problem description. Why not? What happened? Why is that wrong?

Comment: `code`
Aws::Utils::DateTime startdt = Aws::Utils::DateTime::DateTime("2019-10-23T10:00:00Z", DateFormat::ISO_8601); Aws::Utils::DateTime enddt = DateTime::Now(); Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest object_request; object_request.SetBucket(bucket_name); object_request.WithIfModifiedSince(startdt); object_request.SetIfModifiedSince(startdt); The method is not returning any object(file) from s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

1. List all the files from the AWS S3 bucket using ListObjectRequest() & ListObjects()
2. iterate through all the files 1 by 1

   - pass file name as key to getobjectrequest()
   - pass startdate to GetObjectRequest using WithIfModifiedSince()
   - pass enddate to GetObjectRequest using WithIfUnmodifiedSince()
   - call GetObject()

This will return you the object from s3 bucket only if its created or modified within given datetime range.

But its not the most efficient solution, since we are sending separate GetObject () request for each file to aws s3 which is increasing the requests made to s3.

Please let me know if there is a more efficient way to get all files within a given datetime range in a single request.

Comment: Why are you calling `GetObject()` for each object? The `ListObjects()` call returns a `LastModifiedDate`. Just write an `if` statement to check whether that date is within your desired range.

Comment: you are correct John thanks... i missed did not notice that method was present already in ListObjects() objects. wasted an entire day looking for an alternative. thanks..!!!